# Linkedin : get 'People Also Viewed' based on person's email id

Tags: javascript, node.js, linkedin-api

I am working on nodejs project, now I got a new requirement where I have to get 
list of people who viewed person's linked in profile based on email address.

eg. If I have a person's email address, then I want list of peoples(name, photo and email address) who viewed that person's profile.

I tried using linkedin JavaScript SDK, but I didn't find any api which will return this data.

I would be thankful if someone could help me.

Comment: will I get this details if I register to linkedin partner program?